# Chrome/WebKit creating a solid bar when using background, border-radius, and top/bottom borders

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, css

Google Chrome is acting buggy using border-radius, background color, and top and bottom borders. Here's the evidence and code to reproduce:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/6ADtd/4/

```
<div></div>​
```

```
div {
  background:blue;
  border-top:10px solid red;
  border-bottom:10px solid red;
  border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
  height:100px;
  /*
  border-right:1px solid transparent;
  */
}
```

The `border-right:1px solid transparent;` is a trick suggested in the comments which did help remove the unwanted middle solid bar, but when you **resize** the window/browser - it appears again. It has something to do with the proximity of the element to the edge of the browser window, I can't quite understand it. You have to resize then hover over the element sometimes.
 ​
Videos from my desktop:

- http://www.screenr.com/6wU8 (without border-right)
- http://www.screenr.com/NVU8 (with border-right)

I've tried `-webkit-` prefixes on several properties and was unable to fix it.

I first posted this because I needed a quick fix for a specific website, but now I'm noticing it show up on several sites and I've nailed down what causes it. That's what I get for not testing in anything but Firefox. This is probably a bug and I should report it, but I'm still stuck in need of a fix in the meantime.

The ideal solution is with CSS, so I can write one or two selectors  in the CSS file for the fix instead of digging through loads template files and in the database to apply div-wrap or other markup fixes. Does anyone know any tricks to get rid of this bug?

Comment: I don't see that with the nightly WebKit build and Safari.

Comment: Thanks, that at least narrows it down then. Check it out in Chrome (my version is 17, the client complained about it so they see it too, whichever version they're using). You can see it in the video I posted too if it's not reproducible in your version of Chrome.

Comment: Seems you can get rid of it by adding a rule like `border-right:1px solid transparent;`.

Comment: @j08691: Lol yes looks like that works in the demo, but when I applied it in production it didn't seem to do anything. I'll try to produce a demo of your fix working and one not working... [Here is the live site](http://ctvetcenter.com/) if you want to give it a shot with the developer tools or something.

Comment: @j08691: Ok check this out (uses your fix) http://jsfiddle.net/6ADtd/3/ If you don't see the solid bar at first, resize the "Result" panel then hover over the logo, now it's making triangle shapes on the right side O.o What is the meaning of this insanity?!

Comment: Hmmm, in this new example I'm not seeing the blue bar nor these mysterious triangles you speak of, even after re-sizing and hovering.

Comment: I get no triangle on the live site after adding your patch, it's just the same as it was this morning. So weird. Update: The issue on the live site was gone for a sec, then reappeared after resizing the browser and hovering the logo, just like the fiddle. Edit2: Ahhh this is so frustrating, now it's showing up all the time again! All I did was add your patch.

Comment: I experienced this issue with the A1 theme in Redmine. I am using Chrome 18 on OSX. The transparent right border hack fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @matt: Did you, or do you still, experience this bug when resizing the browser like this?: http://www.screenr.com/NVU8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of me looking into this question, there was still an issue [on the prod website](http://ctvetcenter.com/) visible when the browser is resized to force horizontal scrolling on the document:

[image: fits horizontally - no defect]
[image: scrolls horizontally - visible defect]

The "solution" I used was to apply both

```
border-left:1px solid transparent;
border-right:1px solid transparent;
```

to `#header` with developer tools - this seems to force the issue to go away regardless of resizing, at least on a Mac Chrome 18.

This seems like buggy behaviour to me - I'd speculate it would have something to do with blending corners where colors intersect, which, because of a bug, end up bleeding into the element itself.

I've attempted to, rather fruitlessly, look into the possible connection between a border radius higher than the border width causing this behaviour. This was, of course, [untrue](http://jsfiddle.net/6ADtd/10/) - playing around with different x-/y-radii yielded no results without having the "solution" from the above applied. Good to know I guess.

Comment: Ah I can't believe I didn't even try this! This solves the resize issue perfectly for me. Thanks a ton, I just haven't had enough time to play around with this annoying little bug. It's a [little weird](http://jsfiddle.net/6ADtd/11/) with borders over 2px or so, but totally worth it. I had theories that it was triggered by even or odd px in the border/border-radius or using linear-gradient and all kinds of other stuff, didn't even try something this simple.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was being a bit lazy with my initial reply.

What about wrapping a div with the border properties around the header with overflow hidden:  http://jsfiddle.net/jugularkill/Jsdcz/

Comment: I think you should read about shorthand notation in CSS, your code would put the radius on every corner at 15px, mine only sets it on the top left and top right. For example, `3px 2px 1px` would mean top-left 3px, top-right 2px, bottom-right 1px, bottom-left 2px. Just look up shorthand notation for borders. Your code is the same as just `15px`. By the way, your demo link is the same exact one as in my question.

Comment: Just updated my answer, sorry about that: I use short hand on CSS just not with border-radius, transform matrix and a handful of others, though I'll definitely give it a try thanks.

Comment: The problem is, I can't just cut off the corners of the inner element background (the one with the gradient) by using `overflow:hidden` on the outer one, I have elements that are positioned outside the header a bit that need to be visible: http://jsfiddle.net/Jsdcz/1/ Otherwise, this is a fair workaround and I appreciate your idea very much. User j08691's fix from the comments solved the main issue, so this is low-priority for me now on a Friday especially, I'll return to grant you the checkmark if no better solutions arise.

Comment: I agree, it's kind of trivial tho...1 other solution comes to mind: So you have a container div "#header-main" contains two children with position:absolute,top 0,left:0, "#header-fix" (background as a gradient without the cat or logo z-index:0) an a new one "#logo-ele" containing your logo and cat(z-index:1). This way header-fix can remain hiding the overflow and the cat is just a sibling. (just a workaround)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen such behaviour in Chrome, very buggy indeed.
Anyway, you can get rid of border-bottom and it will work alright. If possible, just add a `<div>` with background red at the bottom. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6ADtd/5/

Or a CSS only solution, add content after your div:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/6ADtd/6/

Comment: Adding more divs isn't going to work for me as it is too much work to fix every occurrence of every element (as mentioned in the question). Dropping the bottom border and replacing with `:after` content isn't a bad idea but it's got a few small problems as well. (Also I should have mentioned that I can't assume I know the element's height - I just hardcoded it for the demo) So, I changed the fiddle a bit, I'm just trying to get it to behave more like a border and less like an outline: http://jsfiddle.net/6ADtd/7/ Will work on it tonight - thanks for the idea, I think this might be the trick.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Actually your version works better. And I'm curious to see how you manage to fix that issue. Good luck!