# Border-Radius on Video Element is causing artefacts in Chrome Browser

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

So I have come across an interesting bug for which I haven't been able to find a solution yet, I have tried the ones I could think of to no result. The issue is as follows -

There are artefacts (horizontal and vertical see-through lines) on the video element if -

1. `border-radius` is directly applied to the video element.
2. `border-radius` is applied to the parent of the video element, with `overflow: hidden`.

Example code -

```html
<html>
  <body style="color: #fff;background-color: #00f;">
    <p>
      Original video is hosted at -
      <a style="color: #fff" 
         href="https://streamable.com/6jly2">
        https://streamable.com/6jly2
      </a>
      (create a download link and use it here)
    </p>
    <h1>Border Radius on VIDEO</h1>
    <video width="400px" style="border-radius: 30px;" autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="https://dl3.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    </video>
    <h1>Border Radius on Parent DIV</h1>
    <div style="display: inline-block;border-radius: 30px;overflow: hidden;">
      <video width="400px" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="https://dl3.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
      </video>
    </div>
    <h1>Border Radius with Child DIV</h1>
    <div style="display: inline-block;border-radius: 30px;overflow: hidden;">
      <div style="background-color: yellow;width: 400px;height: 225px;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example screenshot (focus hard to see the white lines) -

[image: Example showing artefacts on the video element]

In the screenshot it seems as the lines are white, but actually they are see-through (compression at work :(), you can reproduce the scenario in your local and see the exact phenomena.

I'm using Chrome 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Mac OS X.

I believe that this issue is being caused by clipping logic that might be used to achieve `border-radius` effect, don't know for sure. If anyone knows that this is a well document bug please let me know as I wasn't able to find it and hence asking the community here.

I did manage to find one similar issue here - [Chrome/WebKit creating a solid bar when using background, border-radius, and top/bottom borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912152/chrome-webkit-creating-a-solid-bar-when-using-background-border-radius-and-top)

But doing that resulted to no success. If anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening and what can be the solution (even if not available I will be happy to understand why), please help out.